# run R program through Unix shell script

Tags: r

I am calling a R function from R studio like below

```
source("test.R)
test()
```

I now want to call this using Unix shell script.

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Rscript -e 'source("test.R"); test()'`

Answer (score 6):

"The Unix way" to do this is to add a first line in the so-called [shebang style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
```

to the file `test.R`, and to follow this with

```
chmod 0755 test.R
```

to make it executable.  Then you can just say

```
./test.R
```

and you created a new command.   As you are on Unix you may also like our [littler](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler) alternative to `Rscript` which you can install from CRAN, or use from your distro (ie Ubuntu or Debian)

Answer (score 1):

You could always write another script, newScript.R, that contains:

`source("test.R")
test()`

and then from the command line, you can run:

`Rscript newScript.R`